# ScrollView white space at bottom

Tags: android, gridview, scrollview

I'm having an issue with ScrollView which leaves a blank space at the bottom. It is filled with few TextViews and GridViews and should fill the whole RelativeLayout parent.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".showPictures">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView.../>
            <GridView.../>
        ...
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Does anybody have an idea what's wrong?

Comment: share the screenshot

Comment: Make the Parent View (RelativeLayout) height to match_parent

Comment: set height of scrollview as `wrap_content`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make your relative layout height match parent, also use android:fillViewPort = "true" in your scroll view

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".showPictures">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

//...
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use this code to avoid extra padding on bottom of scroll view:

```
android:overScrollMode="never"
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had a GridView inside a ScrollView that was causing this issue. It turns out the the layout_gravity in the GridLayout as 'center' was causing this issue.

'center_horizontal' makes more sense for a ScrollView anyway, but I added the ScrollView after the original layout was done (using 'center'), when I saw that the elements were going off-screen on some devices, hence the issue.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"  // having this as android:layout_gravity="center" causes extra space at bottom!
        android:columnCount="2">

        ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Give weight to every child in the scroll view including linear layout  with value 1